# Is there a function to modify existing previous/next post link without modifying theme files?

Tags: categories, next-post-link

I was hoping to be able to just add a function just to keep the previous/next post links within the same immediate (not parent) category. Everything I've been able to find so far includes modifying theme files which I'd rather not do. If I have to I will, but I thought I'd see if I really have to first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you just need to add a function you can put that in a new plugin.

Plugins don't have to be complicated: a single file with [a header comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/) will do. e.g. see the [Hello Dolly](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.1.1/wp-content/plugins/hello.php) plugin bundled with WordPress.